# Neo4j: Multiple Possible Nodes from One CSV Column

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I've a CSV file of businesses and business owners that looks something like this:

| S/n | Business | Business_ID | Owned_By | Gender |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Aries Pte Ltd | 12345 | James Bond | Male |
| 2 | Taurus Pte Ltd | 23456 | Daenerys | Female |
| 3 | Gemini Pte Ltd | 34567 | Taurus Pte Ltd | NA |

I would like to create a graph with the businesses as a node, the owner as a node, and a relationship between the business and the owner. For s/n 1 and 2, this is very straight forward:

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "....csv" AS file
MERGE (b:Business {ID: file.Business_ID) 
WITH file, b
MERGE (p:Person {Name: file.Owned_by, Gender: file.Gender}) 
WITH file, b, p
MERGE (b)-[:owned_by] ->(p)
```

But note that a business could also be owned by another business (s/n 3), and that businesses and persons contains different properties (Business_ID and gender). Using the above syntax, I would get two distinct relationships for s/n 2 and 3:

(Taurus Pte Ltd)-[:owned_by]->(Daenerys)

(Gemini Pte Ltd)-[:owned_by]->(Taurus Pte Ltd)

But what I would like is a single relationship showing the entire chain of ownership:

(Taurus Pte Ltd)-[:owned_by]->(Gemini Pte Ltd)-[:owned_by] ->(Daenerys)

How should I go about doing this?

Answer (score 1):

I would introduce a global label for persons and businesses...

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "....csv" AS file
MERGE (b:Entity {ID: file.Business_ID) 
WITH file, b
MERGE (p:Entity {Gender: file.Gender) 
WITH file, b, p
MERGE (b)-[:owned_by] ->(p)
```

I don't really know why you use Gender, probably a typo, but anyway... on the first import use a global node label like :Entity to get the ownership relationship in. In subsequent imports you can add secondary :Person or Business label to nodes if needed.

Comment: Thanks! There's indeed a typo there, I've amended my question accordingly. But you got the gist of what I was trying to ask

Comment: Please upvote this answer if you find it useful